# How did the dagger of Seth get its power?

Tags: mummy-2017

In The Mummy 2017 film.

> Ahmanet tries on two separate occasions to use a specific dagger to kill a human being so that the Egyptian God Seth could come back into human form through the body.  The dagger itself had the power to bring Seth into human form.  The dagger has two parts, including the shaft and a gem. When both parts are intact, the dagger has its power.

**How did the intact dagger get its power?  Is there a specific story that explains this in the dark universe?**  Perhaps Seth himself created the dagger and somehow Ahmanet received it. What is the back story of the dagger?

Answer (score 1):

Ahmanet offers her soul to Set and Set manifests in the world, offering her the dagger.

As the dagger was intended to resurrect Set in the body of whoever was stabbed with it, Set was presumably confined to the Afterlife outside of being summoned and so the dagger was likely brought from the Afterlife also.

So the dagger gets its power either by being a creation of a god, or because it is from the afterlife, or another reason not revealed.